# OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory

Tags: python, anaconda, spacy, oserror

I know this question has been asked a couple of times but no matter how many solutions I've tried to run I still get the same error. This is the error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-248-fdd700a1da8b> in <module>
      8 STOPLIST = set(list(text.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS))
      9 KEEP_POS = {'ADJ', 'ADP', 'ADV', 'NOUN', 'VERB'}
---> 10 nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
     11 
     12 def scrubbing_text(reviews):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py in load(name, disable, exclude, config)
     45     RETURNS (Language): The loaded nlp object.
     46     """
---> 47     return util.load_model(name, disable=disable, exclude=exclude, config=config)
     48 
     49 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/util.py in load_model(name, vocab, disable, exclude, config)
    327     if name in OLD_MODEL_SHORTCUTS:
    328         raise IOError(Errors.E941.format(name=name, full=OLD_MODEL_SHORTCUTS[name]))
--> 329     raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
    330 
    331 

OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

I'm using Anaconda on a mac. I can see the spaCy folder on the lefthand side but for some reason it won't work. Please help :(

Comment: Could you please provide more information? Have you downloaded the model `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're using anaconda, you need to activate your conda environment before downloading the `en_core_web_sm` model.

1. If you don't have an anaconda environment, first run `conda create -n $envName`, replacing `$envName` with whatever name you want.
2. Activate your environment with `conda activate $envName` (again, replace the variable with whatever you put in step 1.
3. Then install spacy with `conda install spacy`.
4. Finally, run `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`.

Now, when you import spacy and try to load the model, it should work.

Comment: More context: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3226#issuecomment-460463178

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but thanks, it worked!

Comment: @Adorable why not mark the answer of Ray Johns as an 'answer' because his answer solved my problem too :)

Answer (score 1):

Just give this command. Change the version accordingly.

> pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.5.0/en_core_web_sm-3.5.0.tar.gz